# jQuery -- recalculateTotal - add and subtract Price on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm jQuery's newbie so I go by trial and ask the more experienced help.

This is the part of the code

```
 click: function () { //Click event
  if (this.status() == 'available') { //optional seat
   var maxSeats = 3;
   var ms = sc.find('selected').length;
   //alert(ms);
   if (ms < maxSeats) {

                price = this.settings.data.price;

                /*
                    $('<option selected>R'+(this.settings.row+1)+' S'+this.settings.label+'</option>')
                    .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                    .attr('value', (this.settings.row+1)+'_'+this.settings.label)
                    .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                    .appendTo($cart);
                */

                    $('<option selected>R'+(this.settings.row+1)+' S'+this.settings.label+'</option>')
                    .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                    .attr('value', this.settings.id)
                    .attr('alt', price)
                    .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                    .appendTo($cart);

                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length+1);

                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc));
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc));

                return 'selected';
            }
                alert('You can only choose '+ maxSeats + ' seats.');
                return 'available';

        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked

                //Update Number
                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length-1);
                //update totalnum
                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc));
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc));

                //Delete reservation
                $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
                //optional
                return 'available';

        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') { //sold
            return 'unavailable';

        } else {
            return this.style();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem in particular is in part related to the recalculation of the total

```
        $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc));
        $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc));
```

in practice this function calculates the total price for each click on a map and recalculates it when the item (deselecting) is again clicked.
When I click to select an item, the function calculates the total correctly, when I click again an item to deselect it, in the first de-selection (or click), the amount is not subtracted.

To be more concrete give you an example:
If I select three items for the price of 10 euro each, with each click the total is updated correctly (10 + 10 + 10 = 30);
When I deselect the three elements, when i do the first click the total is not updated while in the following click (deselection) the total is updated so it does not return = 0 but 10.

So, I find no element selected, but the total takes me 10!

I tried to include this change but the calculation is completely wrong

```
...........
...........
                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+this.settings.data.price);
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc)+this.settings.data.price);
                return 'selected';

            }

                alert('You can only choose '+ maxSeats + ' seats.');
                return 'available';

        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked
......
......
                //update totalnum
                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-this.settings.data.price);
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc)-this.settings.data.price);
```

any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: (Not really sure about the dupe, because relevant HTML code seems to be missing from question. But even if it is not checkboxes, but select fields, I think the issue is the same - `click` fires _before_ the actual change of the value/selection occurs; `change` is the event you want in such cases.)

Comment: If You look at this `$counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length+1);` and this `                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length-1);` you find that for counter the solution is add +1 and subtract -1. So find something like this

Comment: No clue what you mean.

Comment: @CBroe THE SOLUTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is THE SOLUTION

just move up

```
            //Delete reservation
            $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
```

before

```
            //update totalnum
            $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc));
            $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc));
```

Here it is the complete correct code

```
    click: function () { //Click event
  if (this.status() == 'available') { //optional seat
   var maxSeats = 3;
   var ms = sc.find('selected').length;
   //alert(ms);
   if (ms < maxSeats) {

                price = this.settings.data.price;

                /*
                    $('<option selected>R'+(this.settings.row+1)+' S'+this.settings.label+'</option>')
                    .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                    .attr('value', (this.settings.row+1)+'_'+this.settings.label)
                    .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                    .appendTo($cart);
                */

                    $('<option selected>R'+(this.settings.row+1)+' S'+this.settings.label+'</option>')
                    .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                    .attr('value', this.settings.id)
                    .attr('alt', price)
                    .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                    .appendTo($cart);

                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length+1);

                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc));
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc));

                return 'selected';
            }
                alert('You can only choose '+ maxSeats + ' seats.');
                return 'available';

        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked

                //Update Number
                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length-1);

                //Delete reservation
                $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();

                //update totalnum
                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc));
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc));


                //optional
                return 'available';

        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') { //sold
            return 'unavailable';

        } else {
            return this.style();
        }
    }
});
```